# Avoid regex on a substring enclosed by a character

Tags: python, regex

I have a requirement where I have a string input which contains words which may contain alphabets [a-zA-Z] and digits [0-9].  I want to be able to separate each of such words so that a space is inserted between the alpha part and the digit part.
For example, for the string

```
"5n7x Jahalducro) P4J99UMH9 (MD) auntud C D T)",
```

the word "P4J99UMH9" will be converted to "P 4 J 99 UMH 9"
I have a couple of regex which does this sequentially using re.sub() in Python

```
import re
text = "5n7x Jahalducro) P4J99UMH9 (MD) auntud C D T)"
# For <alpha><number><alpha>    
text = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])([\d]+)(?=[a-zA-Z])', r' \1 '),text)
# For <alpha><number><space>
text = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])([\d]+)(?=\s)', r' \1')
```

Now I also want the ability to mark certain words in the string where these regex should not work.  I would like to do this by enclosing them in a special character like ~ like

```
"5n7x Jahalducro) ~P4J99UMH9~ (MD) auntud C D T)"
```

How do I write the regex for this?

Comment: Any luck with the regexes?

Comment: There could be some way, which I didn't have time to figure out.  So I  worked around it by writing two functions, the first which will remove the words which need to excluded and another which will reinsert them.  Since they are member functions of a class, I could store it in an internal variable

Comment: Oh? So you aren't using the regex after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem with something like this:

```
import re
s = "5n7x Jahalducro) P4J99UMH9 (MD) auntud C D T)"
word_to_enclose = '5n7x'
enclosed_s = re.sub(r'(%s)' % word_to_enclose, r'~\1~', s)
re.sub(r'((?:[A-Za-z](?=\d+(?![A-Za-z\d]*~)))' \
    + r'|(?:\d+(?=[A-Za-z](?![A-Za-z\d]*~))))', r'\1 ', enclosed_s)
```

The result will be:

```
'~5n7x~ Jahalducro) P 4 J 99 UMH 9 (MD) auntud C D T)'
```

Explanation of regex pattern:

It is checking for one of to situation `((?:...)|(?:...))`.
The first one is letter ended with number in the word that is not ended with ~ `[A-Za-z](?=\d+(?![A-Za-z\d]*~)`. The second one is the numbers ended with letter `\d+(?=[A-Za-z](?![A-Za-z\d]*~)` in the word that is also not ended with ~. For this matches the trailing space have to be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a positive lookahead in the regex:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])([\d]+)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?=(?:[^~]*~[^~]*~[^~]*)*$)
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/zH1yS7)

The `(?=(?:[^~]*~[^~]*~[^~]*)*$)` part checks that there is an even number of `~` (or none) ahead of the part to match.